# Split unit test units into a number of files in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a project built using Django and I use unittest library to do some tests, I write all the tests in tests.py file and then I run these tests with the command:

```
./manage.py test app
```

Everything works without a problem, but the tests.py file gets bigger and more complex over time, is there a simple way to split this file into a number of files so that each file contains only one type of tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at test discovery in Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

> Test discovery is based on the unittest module’s built-in test
> discovery. By default, this will discover tests in any file named
> “test*.py” under the current working directory.

This means that you can have files named like `test_feature.py`, `test_api.py` and all of these will be discovered by the management command.

The reason `tests.py` is detected is that it also matches the `test*.py` pattern.